# JQuery fadeIn on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a webpage with which if you scroll down more than 175px, the "Back To Top" box appears so you can scroll back to the top eaiser.

So to do this, I have set the div for "BackToTop" with "Visibility:hidden", so that it doesn't show on the website on page load, since you will already be at the top of the page.

Then once you scroll past 175px, the "BackToTop" div will fade in.

Only it doesn't. It first shows up instantly, then fades out, then fades back in again on the first load. After this, it operates correctly.

Anyone with any ideas on how to correct?

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/AuLFR/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="BackToTop">Back To Top</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    height:1000px;
}
#BackToTop {
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:120px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-60px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 175) {
        $('#BackToTop').css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });

        $("#BackToTop").fadeIn("slow", function () {});

    } else {
        //  $('#BackToTop').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
        $("#BackToTop").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
    }

});
```

Comment: it works for me - using Chrome/OSx

Comment: @DaveBriand Scroll down quickly, I think it works fine on slow scrolling. Also only happens on the first scroll down. Hit refresh to recreate it.

Comment: Why not just set it to `display:none` initially, instead of adding `visibility`. And `fadeIn` will set it to `display:block` - http://jsfiddle.net/AuLFR/4/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AuLFR/5/

Comment: @ShaunakD Thanks! That worked, I was going to try it before but thought it would do the same thing. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: @Joey add .stop(true,false) or stop(true,true) before fade so it wouldn't queue it...

Comment: @Joey, I had already posted it. Good, that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AuLFR/8/)

Use `display:none` as `fadeIn/Out` work do not visibility property.

```
 $('#BackToTop').css({
    'visibility': 'visible'
 });
```

The `.css()` code above, quickly changes the visibility of the element.

```
#BackToTop {

    display:none
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to fade, you should be changing the opacity property, not visibility; Also, define your jQuery objects outside of the scoll event handler, otherwise it could get expensive.

http://jsfiddle.net/AuLFR/3/

HTML

```
<div id="BackToTop">Back To Top</div>
```

JS

```
var $back_to_top = $('#BackToTop');

$(window).on('scroll', function () {

  if (window.scrollY > 175) {

    $back_to_top.addClass('active');

  } else {

    $back_to_top.removeClass('active');

  }

});
```

CSS

```
html {
    height:1000px;
}
#BackToTop {
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:120px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
}
#BackToTop.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Another user pointed out that just using display:none; instead of "visibility:hidden" would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AuLFR/6/

I checked your css prop to see if it was visible before trying to hide it using this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 175) {
        $('#BackToTop').css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });

        $("#BackToTop").fadeIn("slow", function () {});

    } else {
        //  $('#BackToTop').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
        if($('#BackToTop').css('visibility') == 'visible'){
            $("#BackToTop").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Transitions seems to be better, or at least use stop event, because when scrolling top and back and top and back ... it adds animation to queue and can take forever showing and dissapearing and showing and dissapearing again and again.